# ORA-00936:missing expression -- oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Although I find some related question in Stackoverflow:

[ORA-00936: missing expression oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582103/ora-00936-missing-expression-oracle)

[ORA-00936: missing expression Oracle Apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871815/ora-00936-missing-expression-oracle-apex)

But those is not fit my question:

```
(SELECT t_1.oi1name OI1NAME 
FROM ( select oi1.name oi1name, oi.name oname, b.prodesc, b.foundtime, b.occurrencetime, b.divisionproject, b.pilenumber, b.constructionteam, b.progress, h.pk_group 
from zspm_qa_monthlyreport_b b 
left outer join zspm_qa_monthlyreport_h h on b.pk_monthlyreport_h = h.pk_monthlyreport_h 
left outer join org_itemorg oi on oi.pk_itemorg = h.pk_org 
left outer join org_itemorg oi1 on oi1.pk_itemorg = oi.pk_fatherorg 
where h.dr = 0 and h.billstatus = 1 and b.dr = 0 
and oi.code like CONCAT ( ( select code from org_itemorg where pk_itemorg in () ), '%' ) and h.def1 = '2016-01' ) t_1 
WHERE t_1.pk_group = '0001A2100000000007QL')
```

This is my sql code for query, but I don't know where is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in` list is empty.  I don't think that is allowed.

More importantly, you probably intend this logic:

```
where . . . and
      exists (select 1
              from org_itemorg oio
              where pk_itemorg in (. . .) and
                    oi.code like oio.code || '%'
             ) and
      h.def1 = '2016-01'
```

Your subquery can return more than one row, which would be a problem when you run the query.